How do I use Typesense presets on Laravel Scout?
I've searched on Typesense and Scout docs and the only hints I can see as to how to use Typesense Presets is this:
$products = Product::search($searchTerm)
    ->options(['preset' => 'main_search'])                     
    ->paginate(env('SEARCH_ITEMS_PER_PAGE', 12))                     
    ->appends($request->all());

However it seems like this isn't actually using the search preset as I can change the preset and the results are not matching what is being returned when searching in Typesense.
Any help on how to use Typesense Presets in Scout would be appreciated!

You can use dynamic search parameters like this:
use App\Models\Todo;
 
Todo::search('Groceries')->options([
    'query_by' => 'title, description',
    'preset' => 'your_preset_name'
])->get();

More info in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/scout#typesense-dynamic-search-parameters
